# When to free dynamically allocated pthread_t pointer in C?

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a block of code which enters a case statement. If I encounter the right case, I need to create a new thread and continue performing work. This case statement can be called multiple times, creating multiple, simultaneous running threads.

As such, I was thinking that I would need to create a pthread_t*, malloc some memory for it, and then call pthread_create(). However, do I still need to free the pthread_t*? I don't want to create a memory leak. If I need to free it, how and where should I free it?

Ex:

```
case MY_CASE:
    ; 
    pthread_t* foo = (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
    pthread_create(foo, NULL, SomeFunction, &SomeParameters);
   .
   .
   .
 later
   .
   .
   .
free(foo); // Should this be in the code? If so, where?
/* I need to ensure the main thread keeps running. So, I cannot use pthread_join() */
```

Comment: Are you joining your threads? If yes, I believe after you do it.

Comment: No, I can't use pthread_join(), since I need execution of the main thread to continue. Using join would suspend the main thread until the target thread termintates

Comment: As long as no thread needs it, you can release the structure with `free()` as shown.  However, if you don't know whether there is a thread described by the structure, you will have problems freeing it reliably.

Comment: So maybe detach the threads and keep track when they return and free them after it.

Comment: If the thread is not to be joined, you should be creating it detached in the first place. According to [The Open Group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/systypes.h.html), pthread_t is an arithmetic type and thus there should be no *internal* memory leak. Given the confines of this question, I wouldn't use dynamic allocation *at all*. Create the thread detached and send a temporary `pthread_t tid;` by-address to `pthread_create()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free the memory after you've called `pthread_join(*foo, &retval);`.

If you'd rather poll all the threads to see if they're done, keep an array of open handles around and call [`pthread_tryjoin_np`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_tryjoin_np.3.html) on them. Then call `free` on (and remove from the array) your pointer for threads that have terminated.

Alternatively, you can call [`pthread_detach`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html) on your thread. That's more portable, and will work well if you don't care whether or not your threads have terminated. In that case,
the `pthread_detach` man page says this:

> A new thread can be created in a detached state using [pthread_attr_setdetachstate(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_attr_setdetachstate) to set the detached attribute of the attr argument of [pthread_create(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create)

And you can skip `malloc` entirely.

Comment: But, pthread_join suspends until the child thread terminates. I need the parent thread to be able to continue.

Comment: @Maxthecat: I just saw that. Updated.